# How to parse std::string into Poco::JSON::Object in C++

Tags: c++, json, parsing, poco

Is it possible to parse `std::string` into the `Poco::JSON::Object`?

All I've found was `std::string` -> `Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr` through the Poco::Dynamic::Var and Parser. Why can't I avoid using pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Just dereference the pointer:

```
std::string json_string = "{\"test\" : \"A\"}";
Poco::JSON::Parser parser;
auto result = parser.parse(json_string);
Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr ptr_object = result.extract<Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr>();
std::cout << ptr_object->get("test").toString() << std::endl;

// dereference the pointer
Poco::JSON::Object obj = *ptr_object;
std::cout << obj.getValue<std::string>("test") << std::endl;
```

Or shorter:

```
std::string json_string = "{\"test\" : \"A\"}";
Poco::JSON::Parser parser;
auto result = parser.parse(json_string);
Poco::JSON::Object obj = *result.extract<Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr>();
```